# Ajax call works on chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, firefox, asp.net-ajax

This is my code

```
var clicked = false;

    function bodyUnload() {
        alert(1);
        if (clicked == false)//browser is closed  
        {
            var request = GetRequest();
            request.open("GET", "../TestLogout.aspx", true);
            request.send();
        }
    }

    function GetRequest() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return xmlhttp;
```

In Chrome it functions properly. When I click the browser's close button the TestLogout.aspx.cs page is called and in the page load function of TestLogout.aspx.cs page I have used Session.Abandon(); to abandon the session if the user clicks the close button. It is working fine with chrome but not with firefox and internet explorer. Can any one tell what is happening?

Comment: Where is `clicked` modified? How is `bodyUnload` called? If via the `unload` event, try the `beforeunload` event.

Comment: firefox obviously is quicker at unloading than chrome ... you shouldn't do anything asynchronous in the unload event handler - by the way, you really should look into [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) for modern browsers - note however, sendBeacon always uses `POST`

Comment: Tried with request.open("POST","../TestLogout.aspx",false); but it does not work with chrome and firefox

Comment: I changed from onunload="bodyUnload();" to onbeforeunload="bodyUnload();" in body and it worked fine for me both in firefox and chrome but not in Internet Explorer